# Plot overlapping time series

Tags: python, time-series, matplotlib, plotting

I'm trying to plot my test set and test set predictions to check the differences and see how my autoencoder reconstructed the data, but since I have a test set 30x10 I have a huge visualization problem:
[image]

How can I solve it? This is the code, I'm just showing the first row (X-test[0]), but I have 29 more and I don't how to show all of them properly.

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_test[0].T, label='y_true')
plt.plot(x_test_pred[0].T, label='yhat_conv')
_ = plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Could you give us the shapes of X_test so that we can maybe synthetically reproduce the plot?

Comment: What about plotting the differences - i.e. y_true - yhat_conv (or the other way round) ... basically they look like they are going to have a small'ish variance ..

Comment: And offset a few of them (i.e. add 3 to some of the differences and 6 to some more - if you can control the colours pick them too to make pairs line up easily but be visually different [so you only end up with 2/3 per line row of differences instead of 10]...

Comment: Or eliminate all the ones where the difference is really low and only look at the "worst" ??

Comment: @PSub The shape of X_test is (3000, 10, 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to be pretty, but you just for-loop your code:

```
ax, fig = plt.subplots()
for i in range(30):
    ax.plot(X_test[i].T, label='y_true_' + i)
    ax.plot(x_test_pred[i].T, label='yhat_conv' + i)
plt.show()
```

Because you have so many lines, it would be best to **remove the legend** from the plot as it will be too much information to interpret. You could use additional subplots e.g. `ax,fig = plt.subplots(5,6)` and plot one row on each subplot e.g. `ax[1].plot(first_plot)` etc.

It might be more suitable to generate some summary statistics or differences of the lines (as suggested in the comments). One way would also to plot the error bars/distributions of the lines as shaded regions and **just the line of the average for particular groups**, similar to the [plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html) below:

[image]